# Extract drawline coordinates in App designer

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

How can I get extract the x1, y1, x2, y2 from the roi.Position to matching variables (x1, y1, x2, y2)?

```
function drawLineButtonPushed(app, event)
   roi = drawline(app.myAxes)
   disp(roi.Position);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drawline` allows the user to a draw a line connecting two points `A` and `B` on the chosen axis. The XY positions of `A` (`[Ax Ay]`) and `B` (`[Bx By]`) are simply:

```
roi = drawline(app.myAxes);
Ax = roi.Position(1);
Bx = roi.Position(2);
Ay = roi.Position(3);
By = roi.Position(4);
```